# Logs during rpm installation

Tags: redhat, logging, rpm

I'm able to obtain logs in /var/log/message while installing a package using yum, but I'm not able to find logs when a package is installed using rpm. Is there any option to log rpm installation/updation and upgradation. So that when a package is installed or updated using rpm it must be logged into /var/log/messages or some other directory.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that external logging is a yum extra and not available natively with rpm.

You can query the RPM database, `rpm -qa --last` gives a history of when the current RPM packages were installed, but no information on package deletes.

Comment: We are using centralized syslog server and one of the requirement is to log the installed and updated packages using rpm. Is there any workaround so that when a package is installed using rpm it should be logged in real time. Any suggestions or workaround would be helpful

Comment: @Arun: Why can't you use `yum` to do this?

Comment: @Sven: Installing, updating, deleting using yum is getting logged. But in some cases package installation are done using rpm. Hence I'm looking out for a way to log the installations done using rpm

Comment: The simply don't grant sudo rights to the `rpm` command , yum can also be used to install local rpm packages not present in your repo.